# HTML Button in Firefox and border width

Tags: html, css

This is the HTML button I have:

```
<input ID = "btnModel" value="Submit">
```

This is how it looks in Firefox:

[image]

But when I give its border-width a value:

```
input#btnModel{
    border-width:2px;
}
```

it becomes like this:

[image]

1- It doesn't return to its original shape for any border-width values.

2- In chrome the same thing happens but only for border values over 3px and lower than 1px. So basically it returns to its original state when the border-width value is returned to 2px

3- I've checked all the properties before and after this change, they are all pretty much the same.

Any ideas whats happening?

Comment: Try adding `type="button"` to your input. then it will behave like button everywhere.

Comment: First of all, the `<input>` is missing `type=button`

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the code try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ikashif/tr0ku3rr/2/).

> HTML:

```
<input  ID = "btnModel" value="Submit">
```

> CSS:

```
input#btnModel{
border:4px solid #000;
background-color:#c00;
color:#fff;
text-align:center;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 14px -3px #f2fadc;
border-radius:6px;
}
input#btnModel:hover{
border-width:6px;
}
```